# Unhandled Promise Rejection - AWS lambda Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, async-await

AWS cloudwatch logs below error in **second await call**(shown/mentioned in below snippet code in **abc.controller.js**)

```
ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "UnknownError: 413",
    "reason": {
        "errorType": "UnknownError",
        "errorMessage": "413",
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "413",
        "statusCode": 413,
         ....
}
```

Here is Nodejs code.

**s3-service.js**

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const config= require("../config");

const S3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: config.accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: config.secretAccessKey,
  region: config.region
});

const listBucketFolders = (Key, bucketName) => {
  const params = { Bucket: bucketName, Prefix: filePath };
  return S3.listObjects(params).promise();
}


const getS3Object1= (key, bucketName) => {
  return S3.getObject({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: key }).promise();
}

const getS3Object2 = (key, bucketName) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    S3.getObject({
      Key: key,
      Bucket: bucketName
    }, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err); // tried with resolve(err) so don't end up with any error
      } else {
        resolve(data)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

**abc.controller.js**

```
    const S3Controller = async (items)=>{                                                 // using async

    try{

    console.log("S3Controller Execution initiated");
    const fileContent = [];

    for(const item of items){
        ...
        ... 
        const pathRes = await s3Service.listBucketFolders(item.key, item.bucket);         // first await call

        if(pathRes.Contents.length){ // I get all paths
           ...
           ...
           const actualFilePath= pathRes.Contents[0]; // for example targeting [0]th path
        
           if(actualFilePath?.Key){
        
              // PROBLEM is in below await call where it fails silently and doesn't throw any error in local machine. Problem occurs when code gets pushed to AWS lambda function
        
              const fileBufferContent = await s3Service.getS3Object1(actualFilePath,  item.bucket); // second await call                                                                      
        
              // preparing response with fileBufferContent and added it fileContent array
        
              fileContent.push(preparedResponse);
        
              // tried with s3Service.getS3Object2
              // const fileBufferContent = await s3Service.getS3Object2(actualFilePath, item.bucket);    // but same result. It fails sometimes.
        
        
           } 
        }
    }

    return fileContent;

   }catch(e){
       console.log("exception occurred", e);
   }
}
```

I can confirm it silently fails in second await call sometimes BUT doesn't throw any error in local machine but SOMETIMES throws error in LAMBDA function(pls note NOT EVERYTIME).

**Q:** How can I confirm it that if fails in second await call ?
**A:** That's because if I remove second await call and if I pass hardcoded response then it always works. It never fails even after pushing it to AWS lambda function.

Unfortunately, even after adding `try..catch` block, it doesn't capture or throw or log "exception occurred" msg in AWS cloudwatch.

---